# Chef bootstrap chef-server, deploy my own validation.pem and webui.pem

Tags: chef

I have existing validation and webui private keys that I wish to use on a new chef-server deployment.  Part of my bootstrap template copies these keys to /etc/chef/. When chef-solo does its run and starts chef-server how can I prevent it from overwriting /etc/chef/validation.pem and /etc/chef/webui.pem.

Alternatively, is there a process to replace validation.pem and webui.pem with another pair of keys that I have in hand?  All I can find is instructions on having the server regenerate them.

Answer (score 1):

validation.pem is the private key of a special client in chef server named **chef-validator**. While webui.pem is the private key of chef client webui.

You can regenerate the private/public keys of any client via knife API or chef server web UI.

Personally I would not suggest "replace" a private key but regenerate it because this is sensitive data and you'd better not keep using a special one for a long time. Instead, please regenerate them in a certain period for security reason.

However, it's doable to hack bookshelf data store under `/var/opt/chef-server/bookshelf/data` of your chef 11 server host to change the public key stored in an object file. For example, you can extract the object URL when you performing command `knife client show chef-validator -VV`. I strongly dis-recommend this way because it's hacking.